# How to search matching name in table usidng django query

Tags: django

**How to match Name of test case from table and display related name using django query**

```
class TestcaseCache(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    package_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

**Views.py**

```
def testSearch(request):
    print"in tets search"
    search_test_object=""
    if request.POST:
        print "in form post"
        searchText = request.POST.get('Searchbox')
        print  searchText
        search_test_object=TestcaseCache.objects.all().filter(name__contains=searchText)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this --

```
    def testSearch(request):
        if request.POST:
            searchText = request.POST.get('Searchbox')
            print  searchText
            test_case_name_list=TestcaseCache.objects.filter(name__contains=searchText).values_list('name',flat=True)
            for test_case_name in test_case_name_list:
                 print test_case_name
```

Comment: Hi If I want to search it by name of testcase and by its id and package name ,which i will enter in searchText what will query for it.????
test_case_name_list=TestcaseCache.objects.filter(name__contains=searchText).values_list('name',flat=True).values_list('id',flat=True)values_list('package_name',flat=True)

**Its Not working**

Comment: If you want search by name,id and package name then query will be .... TestcaseCache.objects.filter(Q(name__contains=searchText) | Q(package_name__contains=searchText) | Q(id=searchText)).values_list('name',flat=True)

Comment: import Q using this statement - from django.db.models import Q

Comment: i give input as text in text box it matches with id i.e int field primary key. Its gives error when i give text in put in textbox
**invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'test'**

Comment: **user3563105**
How i get object list in "test_case_name_list"
Plz help